# How to use windows pcap api on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ieee802.1x, peap, winpcap

I want to implement a 802.1X wireless client in windows 7 using PEAP/MSCHAPv2. The 802.1X protocol is a datalink layer protocol, it uses the EAPOL protocol to encapsulate the packets. However, I don't know what lib can I use to send the EAPOL packets. In windows XP, I could use the winpcap to send and receive the EAPOL packets, In windows 7,the WinPcap can capture the TCP/IP packets,however it fails to capture the EAPOL packets.So how can i use the WinPcap to capture the EAPOL packets?

Comment: AFAIK also winpcap works on windows7.

Comment: I use winpcap to send the EAPOL packets in windows 7,but it doesn't work.

Comment: Win7 have some security settings which need to be overridden. Maybe you could get better answers if you made a new question with the title ("using windows pcap api on windows 7"), and maybe on another site (f.e. stackoverflow).